# How to continue a double itemize in a new frame (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, itemize

i want to split an itemize that is inside another itemize because i do not have enough space in the frame (neither using scriptsize):

Example:

```
 \begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item {}
        \item{      
            \begin{itemize}
                \item {}
                \item{}
% I want to go in a new frame and be inside the second itemize
                \item{} 
            \end{itemize} }
    \end{itemize} }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start on the second frame with second level itemization, you can simply give an empty first level item `\item[]`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item1
            \item item2      
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subitem1
                \item subitem 2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize} 
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[] 
            \begin{itemize}
                \item subitem 3
            \end{itemize}
            \item item4
        \end{itemize} 
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See if the following solution works for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item1
        \item item2
        \begin{itemize}
            \item subitem1
            \item subitem 2
\framebreak
            \item subitem 3
        \end{itemize}
        \item item4
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: this solution doesn't enable piece wise covering/uncovering of a frame content.